# How to specify the Height/Width in android crop intent without change it by user?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-gallery

I change outputX/outputY to 100 x and y and then to 1000/1000 x and y but nothing different only resolution changed

```java
Intent getImage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
getImage.setType("image/png");
doesImageChosen = true;
getImage.putExtra("crop", true);
getImage.putExtra("aspectX", 1000);
getImage.putExtra("aspectY", 1000);
getImage.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
getImage.putExtra("outputX", 1000);
getImage.putExtra("scale", true);
getImage.putExtra("outputY", 1000);
```

Comment: Your undocumented and unsupported extras are not going to be honored on most devices. There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) -- please use one.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks I will use a library